Excel: maintain formatting of referenced cell in a linked cell
I have a cell containing a text string with a specific format, e.g. one char underlined, another word in bold.
When I reference the cell through a link (e.g. in B1: =A1) I do get the characters, but I lose any formatting of the original cell. Is there any way to maintain formatting of the original cell in a linked cell?
Example:
A1: value: the quick brown fox
B1:
Formula: =A1  displayed text: the quick brown fox
Obviously this is not about a single cell, but I'm looking for a way to "copy over" varying formats in the referenced cells of a full column to the linked ones in another column.
I suspect this is not possible, but I'm happy to learn ...

This is not possible with formula.

You will need to write a VBA routine to do this. Formulas cannot result in text strings with different character formats.

Makes sense. So I guess it will end up in copying the string char by char, explicitly determining and assinging its format. Before I dive deeper into VBA: Is there a way to determine/assign a full set of format properties of a char in one go, i.e. font, underline, etc. or do I have to scan and assign each property one by one, for each char?
